# starting mongodb outside of path

Tags: mongodb

I've just installed mongodb, and had to install 2.0.4, which I couldn't figure out how to do with 10gen, so followed this tutorial and installed from the tar file.

http://antimalwarelab.com/installing-ubuntu-10-04-1-lts-64-bit-mongodb-2-0-3-lamp-and-rockmongo/

Now, in order to start the server, I have to go to `~/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.0.4/bin` and then  type `./mongod`. But all the guides I see online say to just type `mongod` at the command line.

What do I need to set-up in order to not have to go through the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `~/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.0.4/bin` to your `PATH`. Not sure which distro you use. but just google it.

Comment: Thanks, this link provided the appropriate directions http://askubuntu.com/questions/109381/how-to-add-path-of-a-program-to-path-environment-variable

Answer (score 0):

If you followed these instructions instead:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

I don't think you would be having those issues with your `$PATH`.  As of writing this, 2.0.4 is several revisions old even in the 2.0 branch (now 2.0.8) and 2.2.3 has just hit RC status.  I would recommend using something more up to date.